# How can I get the interface of an object in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to create a class that handles gmail for me, the problem is I'd like the typescript intellisense for said object. However this is not giving me the typings for the google object I am trying to create in the constructor:

```
class Gmail {
    private auth: any;
    google = null;
    messageList: emailListType = ('' as unknown) as emailListType;
    constructor(auth) {
        this.google = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: this.auth }).users;
    }
    async getEmailsInLabel(label: string) {
        //@ts-ignore
        this.messageList = await this.google.messages.list({
            labelIds: [label],
            userId: 'me',
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried to go to the type definition of that function, and found this:

```
import { AuthPlus } from 'googleapis-common';
import { gmail_v1 } from './v1';
export declare const VERSIONS: {
    'v1': typeof gmail_v1.Gmail;
};
export declare function gmail(version: 'v1'): gmail_v1.Gmail;
export declare function gmail(options: gmail_v1.Options): gmail_v1.Gmail;
declare const auth: AuthPlus;
export { auth };
```

The google object seems to be of type gmail_v1.Gmail, However whenever I try to import the gmail_v1.Gmail interface typescript says I cannot import from d.ts files.

I've also tried this:

```
class Gmail {
        private auth: any;
        google = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: this.auth }).users;
        messageList: emailListType = ('' as unknown) as emailListType;
        constructor(auth) {
            this.auth = auth;
        }
        async getEmailsInLabel(label: string) {
            //@ts-ignore
            this.messageList = await this.google.messages.list({
                labelIds: [label],
                userId: 'me',
            });
        }
    }
```

works for typing but doesn't run the function but making the point moot, I've also tried to reassign the google property inside of the constructor making equal to an execution of the google.gmail function: doesn't work.

**TLDR:** How can I set the type of the google property in my class to that of the gmail_v1.Gmail interface? How do I get the interface of an object from an external library? What are the best practices for building classes like this so that the constructor will pass the types to the properties?

Answer (score 1):

import { gmail_v1 } from '../node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/gmail/v1';
is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/googleapis.ts), it seems the interface you are looking for is not exported by the library. If it is not exported, you cannot import it.

You cannot import declaration files (`.d.ts`). They are used by tools, such as editors, to verify code and aid developers.